# Use a cookie instead of a string - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

Instead of the variable username being a variable, I would like it to be a cookie.

How do I set the value to a cookie, and then call it for use.

**JavaScript**

```
var username;

function setUser() {
    var newUser = $('#user').val();

    alert(newUser);
    alert("Username Set");

    username = newUser;
    newUser = "";
    document.write("<br /> Welcome: " + username);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

- Create a cookie :

  ```
  Cookies.set('name', 'value');
  ```
- Read cookie :

  ```
  Cookies.get('name'); // => 'value'
  ```

Your code will be :

```
var username;
function setUser() {
    Cookies.set('newUser', $('#user').val());

    username = Cookies.get('newUser');

    document.write("<br /> Welcome: " + username);
}
```

Hope this helps.